# MongoDB BSON size exceeded even when using GridFS

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs, bson

I am seeing this error while saving documents in a GridFS (MongoDB version: 2.4.9)

```
2015-05-15 10:19:15,409 ERROR [STDERR] com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBObject of size 160038724 is over Max BSON size 16777216
2015-05-15 10:19:15,409 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:291)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.OutMessage.writeUpdate(OutMessage.java:175)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.OutMessage.update(OutMessage.java:62)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.update(DBApiLayer.java:326)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:160)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:800)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:768)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSFile.save(GridFSFile.java:54)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.test.service.state.MongoStateOps.update(MongoStateOps.java:87)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.test.service.state.impl.StateOutputMarshallerImpl$1.run(StateOutputMarshallerImpl.java:45)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
2015-05-15 10:19:15,410 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Here is the code:

```
public void update(String correlatorId, byte[] bytes) {
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if ( gfs )  {
            GridFSDBFile state = gridFs.findOne(correlatorId);
            state.put( correlatorLastModificationDateMappingField, now );
            state.put( correlatorBytesMappingField, bytes );
            state.save();
        } 
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Here is a detailed MongoDB information:

```
db.runCommand("buildInfo")
{
    "version" : "2.4.9",
    "gitVersion" : "52fe0d21959e32a5bdbecdc62057db386e4e029c",
    "sysInfo" : "Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49",
    "loaderFlags" : "-fPIC -pthread -rdynamic",
    "compilerFlags" : "-Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -Werror -pipe -fno-builtin-memcmp -O3",
    "allocator" : "tcmalloc",
    "versionArray" : [
        2,
        4,
        9,
        0
    ],
    "javascriptEngine" : "V8",
    "bits" : 64,
    "debug" : false,
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Did the "maxBsonObjectSize" is only valid for collection documents or it also deals with GridFS too?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using 32 bit mongodb ?

Comment: It's 64 bits. I updated the question.

Comment: What version of the Java driver are you using?  What does the `correlatorBytesMappingField` relate to?  That seems to be the cause of the error.  Is that really meta data or file data?

Comment: I am using the 2.9.3 version. The `correlatorBytesMappingField` is a byte array which holds the content I am saving in GridFS.